# Missing permissions to set up Mulesoft Salesforce connector configuration

Tags: api, soap-api, mulesoft

I'm setting up a Mulesoft Salesforce connector configuration to use [Basic Authentication](https://docs.mulesoft.com/salesforce-connector/10.12/salesforce-connector-studio#basic) to my company's Salesforce org but the connection is failing with message

> Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out.

- I have the correct username, password, and security token for my company's org.
- I have the API Enabled permission on the custom profile I'm using to connect my company's org.
- I can connect to Workbench and Excel Power Query using my company's custom profile.
- I had no issue connecting to my own developer org as System Administrator profile using the steps for Mulesoft [Basic Authentication](https://docs.mulesoft.com/salesforce-connector/10.12/salesforce-connector-studio#basic).

What permissions are missing from the profile I'm using to connect Mulesoft to my company's org?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Which value do you have in authorization url?
For example:

- https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/46.0
- https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/46.0

[image]